# Make a rule rewrite all traffic to a php with the url rewrite module

Tags: php, iis, url-rewriting, web-config

the problem I have is that I can not access the endpoint of my api correctly, always returns a 404 or 403. The api is created with slim in a iis 8 and the structure is as follows:

[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9D6QB.png)

My web.config is located in /v1/Web.config (at the end of the project in the image) and its code is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <configuration>
        <system.webServer>
            <rewrite>
                <rules>
                    <rule name="rule" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
                        <match url="*" />
                        <conditions>
                            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                        </conditions>
                        <action type="Rewrite" url="index.phk" />
                    </rule>
                </rules>
            </rewrite>
        </system.webServer>
    </configuration>
```

I need that when the user calls the url "http://myserverip/api/v1" go find the index.phk file inside the public folder, it does not matter if the user calls an endpoint or the root / v1, it has always to go to index.phk. Thanks for your attention, and sorry for my English.

Comment: what web server config is this from?

Comment: The web sever config is IIS 8

Comment: Ah ok, can't help you then

Comment: Please use failed request tracing to see into the rules, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Comment: @LexLi OK, I'm going to try it

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure the default value of `logicalGrouping` property inside your `<conditions/>` block is `MatchAll`, so by default IIS is trying to match requests that are both a File and a Directory. If you insert `logicalGrouping="MatchAny"` that should match either condition:

`<conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">`

Also, your action needs a leading `/`, and i wont mention you spelled `index.php` `index.phk`...

`<action type="Rewrite" url="/index.php" />`

Comment: I've tried it, but it does not work. The .phk extension is correct, it is adapted to work like this, and in another website it works correctly. Thanks.